# Android: Getting HTTP response incrementally like in iOS

Tags: android, ios, json, streaming, httprequest

I'm relatively new to Android (I'm an iOS-Developer) and I want to call a Webservice like I'm used to in iOS with NSURLConnectionDelegate's method

```
didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

I need to get the data incrementally because I'm building a streaming API that gets a lot of JSON data in response and needs to check the data for complete blocks.

Would be great if someone could help me, I've been searching for a while and didn't find a satisfying solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this with the help of a friend and some links.

You need to implement an own ResponseHandler like this:

```
class ChunkedResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<String> {
    @Override
    public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        int n;

        while ((n = stream.read(b)) != -1) {
            output.append(new String(b, 0, n));  

            // do something while input is streaming
        }

        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

Now you simply have to assign the response handler when starting the request:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("someURL");

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ChunkedResponseHandler();
String responseBody = client.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to call web services in Android you should use the `AsyncTask` where the `request` would be made `asynchronously`. Have a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Every time you're request would be finished the method `onPostExecute(Object result)` would be called. Thats the method where you can go on with further processes.

Comment: Yes, I already know this and my requests are already implemented inside of an AsyncTask. But what I'm searching for is a callback method that returns me the already received data while the request is still running.

Answer (score 0):

The [URLConnection documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) contain following example:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/index.html");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
try {
 readStream(in);
 finally {
 in.close();
}
```

If i right understood your question, just implement readStream function as you need.